# Force WordPress to strip/remove EXIF/IPTC metadata when resizing thumbnails

Tags: post-thumbnails, thumbnails

I am using Imagick with WP 5.0.3. Since version 4.5 WordPress uses Imagick to create/resize thumbnails and it keeps EXIF/IPTC metadata (using GD, metadata are removed).

WordPress keep EXIF/IPTC metadata in thumbnails, but I would like to create new thumbnails without them, to remove metadata. There is **image_strip_meta** filter, but I can not make it work how I would like, to remove metadata. I put this inside my functions.php (inside my theme), but nothing, new thumbnails still have metadata:

```
add_filter ('image_strip_meta', false); // Also tried with "true"
```

I read that there was a bug in WP about this (I don't know if it is fixed).

Could you please tell me what would be the right way to remove metadata from thumbnails?

Comment: The second parameter of `add_filter` needs to be a callable. So it should be `add_filter ('image_strip_meta', '__return_true' );` Although the default is to strip the metadata, so I don't know why your thumbnails still have the metadata.

Comment: I tried your updated code, but metadata (exif is still present in new thumbnails, it is not removed). Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

The Imageick `strip_meta` function is only called if the `image_strip_meta` hook returns true, but the function doesn't actually strip all profiles.  Some are protected, as you can see in the function code:

```
 /*
     * Protect a few profiles from being stripped for the following reasons:
     *
     * - icc:  Color profile information
     * - icm:  Color profile information
     * - iptc: Copyright data
     * - exif: Orientation data
     * - xmp:  Rights usage data
     */
    $protected_profiles = array(
        'icc',
        'icm',
        'iptc',
        'exif',
        'xmp',
    );
```

Comment: Is there any way to remove "exif" from protected_profiles, preferably from my theme's function.php file, so that 'image_strip_meta' filter will work than?